# Change NB project to maven project

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, maven

I have created java desktop application project using NB and now I want to convert it into maven project so everybody will be able to compile it and maintain in eclipse/netBeans. Is there any easy way to do this?

Or maybe there is some way to convert project created using wizard in NB to eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing this for an Enterprise Application, which consists of 3 modules (EJB,EAR and WAR).

Its as simple as creating the new Maven project and copying your .java files into the new project and dependencies into the pom file.